# patch Value in a nested form control using angular2

Tags: angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

I need to set a value in a nested control in a FormBuiler and the model is the following:

```
this.addAccForm = this.fb.group({
      accid: ['', Validators.required],
      status: '',
      cyc: this.fb.array([
        this.initCyc(),
      ])
    })

initCyc() {
      return this.fb.group({
        cycid: ['', Validators.required],
        name: ['', Validators.required],
        description: ['', Validators.required],
        status: ['', Validators.required],
        det: this.fb.group({
            dcycid: ['', Validators.required],
            status: ['', Validators.required]
        })
      })
```

I need to set a value cycid and also dcycid but I m stuck to it, I've tried to use the following  line , but it does NOT help :

```
this.addAccForm.patchValue({cyc: { [0]: {cycid: 1234567 }}});
```

//

```
this.addAccForm.patchValue({cyc: { [0]: { det : {dcycid: 9876543}}}});
```

Any idea how it should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I solved my issue :

```
(this.addAccForm.controls['cyc'].at(0)).patchValue({cycid: 12345 });  
//
(this.addAccForm.controls['cyc'].at(0)).controls['det'].at(0).patchValue({dcycid: 9876543});
```

Thank you

Comment: that's code not work for me, I think version difference, I am using version `^6.0.0`

Answer (score 10):

This did the trick for me:

```
this.addAccForm.patchValue({'cyc': {cycid: 1234567 }});
```

Answer (score 6):

Try with theese codes

```
this.addAccForm.patchValue({cyc: {cycid: 1234567 }});

this.addAccForm.patchValue({cyc: { det : {dcycid: 9876543}}});
```

Another solution is:

```
(< FormGroup >this.addAccForm.controls['cyc']).controls['cycid'].patchValue('1234567');
(< FormGroup >this.addAccForm.controls['cyc']).controls['det'].controls['dcycid'].patchValue('1234567');
```

Comment: just give a try without any success.

Answer (score 5):

### Update

Updating nested fields of an Angular `FormGroup` looks cleaner using the `get` method, like this:

```
this.addAccForm.get('cyc.det.dcycid').patchValue(9876543);
```

And if for some reason you like the object syntax:

```
this.addAccForm.get('cyc.det').patchValue({ dcycid: 9876543 });
```

Answer (score 2):

**Here is the code for working for me.**

I am using Angular Version **"^6.0.0"**

```
var formArray = this.addAccForm.get("cyc") as FormArray;
formArray.at(0)["controls"]["cycid"].patchValue("Value that you want to pass");
```

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, this is an older entry, but that's how I handle similar situations

```
this.addAccForm.controls['cyc']['controls'][index].patchValue({cycid: '100'})
```

The syntax seems cleaner to me like this. However, one fairly easy approach to go through is by simply outputting the form.controls at first. That way you can see in the console what your form consists of and basically just observe its structure.

Answer (score 0):

Define a `FormGroup` to hold a form. 
`addAccForm: FormGroup`

Create a form using `FormBuilder`.

```
this.addAccForm = this.fb.group({
    accid: ['', Validators.required],
    status: '',
    cyc: this.fb.array([])
})
```

Now create a method to patch the form values. You may pass the model as parameters to the method. Or a variable defined in the component class.

```
// GETER TO RETRIEVE THE CYC FORMARRAY
get cycFormArray(): FormArray {
    return this.addAccForm.get('cyc') as FormArray;
}

patchForm(model: any) {
   this.addAccForm.patchValue({
       accid: [model.accid, Validators.required],
       status: model.status,
   });

   // PASS ARRAY TO PATCH FORM ARRAY
   this.patchCyc(model.cyc);
}

// METHOD TO PATCH FORM ARRAY 
patchCyc(cycArray: any[]) {
    cycArray.forEach(item => {
        this.cycFormArray.push({
            this.fb.group({
               prop1: item.prop1,
               prop2: item.prop2,
               ...
            })
        })
    })
}
```

The `patchCyc()` method will loop through the array passed as parameter. A new `FormGroup` will be pushed to the `cyc FormArray` in each loop.

Answer (score 0):

nested form patchvalue you need to use Array after object like this:

```
this.userform.patchvalue({
 name: 'Ajay',
 approvers: [ {id:1} ]
})
```