# Patching value for a nested control 3 levels deep

Tags: angular

I need to patch a value 3 levels deep. I was looking at this answer = [patch Value in a nested form control using angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44322373/patch-value-in-a-nested-form-control-using-angular2) but that only works if you are 2 levels deep.

My form is constructed like this:

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
            Id: [null],
            Languages: {
             en-GB:{
             "Title": "blah"
            }
          }
        });
```

How can I patch the title value?

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
this.myForm.controls['Languages']['en-GB']['Title'].patchValue("other blah");
```

Answer (score 0):

After endless trial and error, this was the correct answer:

```
this.myForm.controls['Languages']['controls']['en-GB']['controls']['Title'].patchValue("other blah");
```